# While forming a REST URL for our application, how should we differentiate two services related to the same object?

Tags: java, rest, url, naming-conventions

need two services related to the object "item".

1. To get the details of the item. Though it is a method to get data, I will be using POST since my pathParam/MatrixParam list is too long(Say, purchaserIds provided in the matrixParam is used to fetch the items they have bought). To avoid "URI too long" exception, I made it POST.
2. To save the item with some details. This will also be a POST method since it is saving/updating.

Now, both services will have the same url http://...../item and both will have httpMethod as POST.

How can we differentiate these 2 services by the URL? Is it right to make it "http://.../item/save" and ".../item/get"?

Comment: Normally you wouldn't use POST to get data. Maybe you could include an example of which parameters/data you wanted to add in the `GET /item` url.

Comment: I need to pass purchaserIds in the url as I added in the description now.

Comment: The problem is that sometimes the purchaserIds are too many that URL max length is exceeded. Hence I am passing purchaserIds in the requestBody and making it POST

Comment: It doesn't matter how you phrase it, if you want it to be a REST interface you should not use POST to get, only GET. Can you explain what is the actual use-case for passing such a large number of purchaserIDs? That may help us understand what you're trying to do and suggest a better way of achieving it.

Answer (score 1):

If your URLs would end up too long, it sounds like your URL design is wrong - GET against `http://.../items/1/purchasers/` would (for example) be a decent URL to return all the people who have bought item 1, then to update item 1, you would PUT to `http://.../items/1/` and to create an item you would POST to `http://.../items/`

The URL scheme you decide does not sound RESTful, as you're using it to describe actions rather than resources - the URL should identify the resource you are accessing rather than what to do to it.

Comment: Thanks. I have added the comments above with the reason for keeping it as POST. Please check. The first service is not to get the purchasers, but to get the items based on the purchaser Ids. Sorry for the confusion , I have edited the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

To get the details of item you will need to use GET method with item id as path parameter.

http://....../itemid

using POST for GET will defeat the purpose and entire design of the api will be disturbed.

Comment: Thanks. I have added the comments above with the reason for keeping it as POST. Please check.